# Pandas Drop rows that do not contains a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I will start by saying I am not an expert in pandas and I do apology if my question sounds so basic.

I have csv file that have 5 columns, as follow:

```
timestamp.   message.  name.   destinationuserna.   source username
time.         hello.   hello.    user1.                user1
time.         hello.   hello1.    user2.                user1
time.         hello.   hello2.    user3.                user1
time.         hello.   no.       user3                user1
time.         hello.   don't.    random.                user1
```

This is just a basic example, but what I would like to do, is to check the column `name` and drop all the rows where the column `name` does not contain `hello`,`hello1` or `hello2`.

Can please any expert help me to understand how I can achieve this?

I tried with this line of code, but it didn't work at all:

```
f[f['name'].str.contains("hello1")]
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. Perhaps drop the `1` in `hello1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using `isin`

To check for multiple values in a column you can use Pandas `isin`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

names_to_keep =  ['hello', 'hello1', 'hello2']

df = df[df['name'].isin(names_to_keep)]

print(df)
```

```
Sample Output
  timestamp message    name destinationuserna sourceusername
0      time   hello   hello             user1          user1
1      time   hello  hello1             user2          user1
2      time   hello  hello2             user3          user1
```

### Using `query`

Another method would be to use Pandas `query`.

```py
df  = df.query(f'name in {names_to_keep}')
```

### Using `startswith`

If you only want to keep rows that start with a particular value you could use `startswith`.

```py
df = df[df['name'].str.startswith('hello')]
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I do have another question related to this topic. How can I pass 2 columns in `isin`? if I want check another list of strings in message for example?

Comment: You would add another `isin`, e.g. `df[df['name'].isin(names_to_keep & df['message'].isin(messages_to_keep )]`

Comment: I tried this approach, but the `&` removes all the logs related to `names`

Comment: What exactly did you try? Perhaps you should open another question?